# Setting default values (conditional assignment)

Tags: php, ruby, logical-operators

In Ruby you can easily set a default value for a variable

```
x ||= "default"
```

The above statement will set the value of x to "default" if x is nil or false

Is there a similar shortcut in PHP or do I have to use the longer form:

```
$x = (isset($x))? $x : "default";
```

Are there any easier ways to handle this in PHP?

Answer (score 47):

As of PHP 5.3 you can use the ternary operator while omitting the middle argument:

```
$x = $x ?: 'default';
```

Comment: A problem with this is that PHP may throw a notice about an undefined variable, and if you do it a lot it will clutter the output/logs depending on what you have the reporting level set to.

Answer (score 12):

As of PHP 7.0, you can also use the [null coalesce operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)

```
// PHP version < 7.0, using a standard ternary
$x = (isset($_GET['y'])) ? $_GET['y'] : 'not set';
// PHP version >= 7.0
$x = $_GET['y'] ?? 'not set';
```

Comment: "syntactic sugar" indeed :) The docs state the operator can be chained: `$username = $_GET['user'] ?? $_POST['user'] ?? 'nobody';`

Answer (score 7):

```
isset($x) or $x = 'default';
```

Comment: That'll work as long as we don't consider false values of $x to be 'set'.

Comment: $x === false and $x = 'default';
isset($x) or $x = 'default';

Comment: @Adam - that's true, but the same can be said for ruby's "||=" notation: `x = false; x ||= true; x #=> true`

Answer (score 3):

As of PHP 7.4 you can write:

```php
$x ??= "default";
```

This works as long as `$x` is `null`. Other "falsy" values don't count as "not set".

Answer (score 2):

I wrap it in a function:

```
function default($value, $default) {
    return $value ? $value : $default;
}
// then use it like:
$x=default($x, 'default');
```

Some people may not like it, but it keeps your code cleaner if you're doing a crazy function call.

Comment: The "problem" with wrapping it in a function call is that all the arguments get evaluated. In a = b || c, c only gets evaluated if b is falsey. This may or may not be what you want.

Comment: One would hope that you're not actually calling side-effecting methods in an assignment anyway.

Comment: @KaptajnKold You can pass by ref, then the arguments won't be evald ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think your longer form is already the shortcut for php... and I wouldn't use it, because it is not good to read

Some notice:
In the symfony framework most of the "get"-Methods have a second parameter to define a default value...